# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

Here is my testRunner class:
Not yet completed.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/test/resources/features/dhlcj", 
glue="dhl.gaqcjqa.fsApi.steps")
public class TestRunnerFsApi {

}
```

and my dependencies:
I am not sure if the versions can be matched.

```
<dependencies>

<!-- Junit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Cucumber Junit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Cucumber VM -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Gherkin -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Rest Assured -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Rest Assured Json Path -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Rest Assured Schema Validator -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Rest Assured Common -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured-common</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

here is the picture of my project structure:
[image]

Could you explain why ma I getting this error?
I am using Maven but at that time I was excepting the code from test runner class by right click on the page and run!

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems!

1. You are using 3 different versions of Cucumber mixed together. Make sure that all `cucumber-` dependencies have the same version. Latest is v6.1.1
2. You are mixing `cucumber-junit` and `cucumber-testng` together. Remove `testng`, `cucumber-testng` as well as any imports from `io.cucumber.testng`.
3. Your junit version should be 4.13 to match the one from the most recent `cucumber-junit`.
4. The glue should be a package name:

   ```java
   @CucumberOptions(
      features = "src/test/resources/features/dhlcj",
      glue = "dhlcj.test.cucumber.steps"
   )
   ```

Comment: I did some changes. Please have a look. The error still persists

Comment: The issue has been resolved. It was all about version mixed up. Thank you.